# How to persist an object for longer than a request

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to implement a very simple api. It should instantiate a tv object which status should be changed (from off to on and from on to off). My current problem is that after I change the status in a get-method the tv object is reinstantiated.

Is there a simple way to persist the object for longer than one request?

Here my code:

```
public class TvController : ApiController
    {
       Tv tv = new Tv(null, null, false);

        // GET: api/Tv
        [HttpGet]
        public bool Get()
        {

            if (!tv.Status) { tv.Status = true; }
            else { tv.Status = false; }

            return tv.Status;
        }


public class Tv
    {
        public  string Channel { get; set; }
        public  string Volume { get; set; }
        public  bool Status { get; set; }

       public Tv(string channel, string volume, bool status)
        {
            Channel = channel;
            Volume = volume;
            Status = status;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your API is stateless, you would need to figure out a way to persist the request with some sort of lookup table (perhaps you store the API key along with the object associated with it in a Redis node)

I'm not sure you can use `Session` with an API Controller as that likely defeats the whole point, but if you could, you would do the following.

And your code would need to be updated to do this:

```
if( Session["TVObject"] == null) {
  Tv tv = new Tv(null, null, false);
  Session.Add("TVObject", tv);
} else {
  Tv tv = Session["TVObject"] as Tv;
}
```